# Get specific value Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have car table with status field and there's "available", and "breakdown". 
I also got fleet CRUD, once I add fleet I want to show car with only "available" status. what should I add ?

here's my fleet controller code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Models\Fleet;
use App\Models\Car;
use App\Models\Attendance;
use App\Helpers\Enums\FleetStatus;
use App\Models\AttendanceDetail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;
use App\Http\Controllers\Base\MasterController;
use Route;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class FleetController extends MasterController
{
protected $detailView = 'fleet.show';
protected $indexView = 'fleet.index';
protected $createView = 'fleet.form';
protected $editView = 'fleet.form';

protected $routeBindModel = 'fleet'; //Route Model Binding name in RouteServiceProvider
protected $redirectPageWhenFormSuccess = 'fleet.index'; //Route Name
protected $title = 'Fleet';

public function save(Request $request, $obj = null) {

    if (!$obj) {
        $obj = new Fleet;
    }
    return $this->saveHandler($request, $obj);
}

//Must have this method if need datatable;
public function datatableBuilder($obj = null) {
    return Fleet::query();
}

public function makeDatatable($obj) {

    return Datatables::of($obj)
    ->addColumn('action', function ($model) {
            return $this->makeActionButtonsForDatatable($model);
    })
    ->editColumn('status', function($model){
        return FleetStatus::getString($model->status);
    })
    ->make(true);
}

public function render(View $view, $route = null, $obj = null, $method = 'POST') {
    $statusList = FleetStatus::getArray();
    $carStatusList = Car::pluck('plate_no', 'id');
    $attendanceList = Attendance::pluck('driver_id', 'id');
    $workingHourList = Attendance::pluck('working_hours', 'id');
    $view->with(compact('statusList', 'carStatusList', 'attendanceList', 'workingHourList'));
    return parent::render($view, $route, $obj, $method);
}
}
```

here's my add form code :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Car </label>
                                {!! Form::select('car_id', $carStatusList, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this will create a list of available cars:

```
Car::where('status','available')->pluck('plate_no', 'id');
```

Comment: do u know how to show the driver name instead of ID ?
driver_id is linked to attendance->attendace_detaill->fleet

Comment: you need to creste a relationship between the car and the driver in the driver model add public function car(){ return $this->belongsTo('Models\Car'); } and in the car model add  function driver(){ return $this->hasMany('Models\Driver'); } This will work assuming you have a one to many relationship between drivers and cars . Then just go $car->driver->name; You can apply this to any relationship more info here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @Indra I did create relationships. Im using yajra datatable to load all the data.

Comment: There should be no issue with yajra and this implementation, but without seeing your models and your table rendering it's hard to figure out the problem. Since this question it's already answered please contact me on the private chat for help

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this:

```
$carStatusList = Car::where('status', 'available')->pluck('plate_no', 'id')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your model add a scope

```php
public function scopeAvailable($query){
    return $query->where('status', '=', 'available');
}
```

And then wherever you need to use it:

```php
Car::available()->get()
```

or

```php
Car::available()->pluck('plate_no' , 'id');
```

More info here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#query-scopes